# Special case of Schur-Zassenhaus theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The theorem of Schur-Zassenhaus says that

> *if $G$ is a finite group, and $H$ is a normal subgroup, such that $|H|$ and $|G/H|$ are relatively prime, then $G$ contains a subgroup $K$ of order equal to $|G/H|$.*

(this subgroup $K$ will then be obviously a complement of $H$, i.e. $K\cap H=1$)

If we see the proof, then the non-trivial part comes in the case when *$H$ is abelian.*

Suppose we put one more extra condition: *$H$ is central in $G$.* Then is it easy to prove the theorem *without (co)homological methods*? Putting this a a question:

> *Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a subgroup in center of $G$ such that $|H|$ and $|G/H|$ are co-prime. Then prove that $G$ contains a subgroup of order equal to $|G/H|$.*

Comment: If I remember correctly, there should be a proof of SZ without any (explicit) use of (co)homological machinery in "Finite group theory" by Martin Isaacs.

Answer (score 1):

Burnside's normal complement theorem states that if a Sylow $p$-subgroup is central in its normalizer, then it has a normal complement. This result can be proven with transfer and a proof can be found in many textbooks on basic group theory.

Apply this to Sylow $p$-subgroups of $H$ (which are in this case Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ as well) to find a normal complement for $H$.

Comment: But surely that is no easier than the standard proof of the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I agree. But it avoids group cohomology which was asked for..

Comment: I am not convinced! There are proofs of the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem that do not mention cohomology explicitly, they just use an averaging argument over group elements. The transfer proof could also be regarded as an averaging argument.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen: If you look at the elegant proofs of Schur-Zassenhaus for an abelian normal subgroup and of the basic properties of the transfer homomorphism given in the book "The Theory of Finite Groups" by Kurzweil and Stellmacher, you'll see how closely related both are (as Derek already commented).

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but I am going to write out what I think is the standard averaging proof and show that it is already quite short. I leave you the exercise of checking that it gets even a little shorter if you assume $H$ (soon called $A$) is central. The real reason I am writing this is that I plan to teach it next term, and I want to practice.

I'm going to change to notation I prefer. Let $A$ be an abelian group, written additively, and let $G$ be a finite group such that multiplication by $|G|$ is invertible on $A$. Let 
$$1 \to A \overset{\exp}{\longrightarrow} \tilde{G} \to G \to 1$$
be a short exact sequence, where $\tilde{G}$ and $G$ are written multiplicatively. We must split the map $\tilde{G} \to G$.

We write $\log$ for the inverse of $\exp$, and $\rho$ for the action of $G$ on $A$. So $\tilde{g} \exp(a)  =  \exp(\rho(g) a)\tilde{g}$ for any $\tilde{g} \in \tilde{G}$ with image $g \in G$.

Begin with a set-theoretic splitting $s: G \to \tilde{G}$. For $g$ and $h$ in $G$, let $\phi(g,h)$ be the unique element of $A$ such that
$$s(gh) = s(g) \exp(\phi(g,h)) s(h).$$

For any $g_1$, $g_2$, $h$ all in $G$, we have
$$s(g_1 g_2 h) = s(g_1 g_2) \exp(\phi(g_1 g_2,h)) s(h) = s(g_1) \exp(\phi(g_1, g_2 h)) s(g_2) \exp(\phi(g_2, h)) s(h)$$
so
$$s(g_1 g_2) \exp(\phi(g_1 g_2,h)) = s(g_1) \exp(\phi(g_1, g_2 h)) \cdot s(g_2) \exp(\phi(g_2, h)). \quad (\ast)$$

Consider the general relationship
$$s(g_1 g_2) \exp(h_3) = s(g_1) \exp(h_1) s(g_2) \exp(h_2)$$
which we can rewrite as
$$h_3 - \rho(g_2)^{-1}\cdot h_1 - h_2 = \log (s(g_1) s(g_2) s(g_1 g_2)^{-1}).$$ 
The latter form is clearly an affine linear equation in $h_1$, $h_2$, $h_3$, so the average of any collection of solutions is another solution.

We therefore average $(\ast)$ over $h \in G$ to get
$$s(g_1 g_2) \exp \left( \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{h \in G} \phi(g_1 g_2,h) \right) = s(g_1) \exp \left( \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{h \in G} \phi(g_1,h) \right) \cdot s(g_2) \exp \left( \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{h \in G} \phi(g_2,h) \right).$$

In other words, $g \mapsto s(g) \exp \left( \tfrac{1}{|G|} \sum_{h \in G} \phi(g,h) \right)$ is a splitting of $\tilde{G} \to G$. $\square$