# Schur-Zassenhaus in finite abelian case

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, exact-sequence

Recently, my professor wrote down the following theorem without a proof:

> **Theorem.** Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, and $H<G$ be a subgroup. If $|H|=m$ and $|G/H|=n$ with $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)$, then $G\simeq H\times G/H$.

This is equivalent to the statement that the short exact sequence of groups

$$0\longrightarrow H\longrightarrow G\longrightarrow G/H\longrightarrow0$$
splits.

After some searching on the internet, I found out that this is a general theorem that goes by the name of Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem. The proofs I found use complicated machinery in group theory, group cohomology, which I haven't seen yet. Is there any proof known of the special case where $G$ is finite abelian?

Comment: Yes, there are elementary proofs for special cases, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456002/special-case-of-schur-zassenhaus-theorem?rq=1) etc. Have you searched this site already? The notes by [K. Conrad](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjwkOrS0c7nAhXKT8AKHRO6B9MQFjABegQIChAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkconrad.math.uconn.edu%2Fblurbs%2Fgrouptheory%2Fschurzass.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3mnRhdNPEZv_JCpQagq_rr) seem to have an elemenatry proof even for the general case.

Comment: I saw those two references. I was hoping it would be possible to explicitly construct some section of the short exact sequence

Comment: The comments by Derek Holt at the linked question say that we don't need any cohomology. What do you think of the proof in Conrad's notes? I think this is better than any struggles with special cases.

Comment: The result can be deduced from the fundamental theorem of abelian groups. Alternatively, in the case when $G$ is nilpotent, it follows from Sylow's Theorem. The general case is more difficult in that it requires an averaging argument.

Comment: @DerekHolt The proof of the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem that I am aware of uses derivations and transversals for the critical case where the normal subgroup is abelian. I am curious what you mean by an "averaging argument". No need to explain in detail; a reference would be just as good.

Comment: @DietrichBurde There's no elementary proof in Conrad's notes.

Comment: I updated the file linked to under my name above so that (1) it is clearer that the proof I wrote up about the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem for the general case is not complete and (2) there is a self-contained (complete) proof in the case that $G$ is abelian on the first page.  See Example 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $G$ is a finite abelian group and $|G| = mn$, where $\gcd(m,n) = 1$. Let $H < G$ be a subgroup of order $m$. Here is a proof which only works in this special case.

First note that $H = \{ x \in G : x^m = 1\}$. Indeed if $x \in H$, then $x^m = 1$ since $H$ has order $m$. Conversely if $x^m = 1$, then $(xH)^m = H$ in $G/H$. On the other hand $(xH)^n = H$ since $G/H$ has order $n$, so $xH = H$ since $\gcd(m,n) = 1$. Thus $x \in H$.

Let $K = \{ x \in G : x^n = 1\}$. For any $x \in G$, we can write $x = yz$, where $y^m = 1$ and $z^n = 1$. (Proof: write $am + cn = 1$ for $a,c \in \mathbb{Z}$, and take $y = x^{cn}$ and $z = x^{am}$).

Thus $G = HK$. Since $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ we have $H \cap K = 1$, so $K \cong G/H$ and $G \cong H \times K$.

Comment: Thanks, precisely what I was looking for! Great to see how we don't need any fancy stuff like Sylow's Theorem and group cohomology in this special case.

Comment: One question, it might be a stupid one: why can we conclude in the last sentence that $K\simeq G/H$?

Comment: @rae306: Since $KH/H \cong K / H \cap K$.

Comment: Really nice, thanks!! :-)

Comment: Sylow's theorem is no "fancy stuff" but really basic material.